# get wrong result when caculating on GPU (python3.5+numba+CUDA8.0)

Tags: python, cuda, numba, numba-pro

I want to get the sum of different parts of an array.
I run my code. and find two problems from what was printed.

*pro1:*

Described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131872/two-values-cant-be-printed-correctly-python3-5numbacuda8-0). It has been solved. Maybe it's not a real problem.

*pro2:*

In my code, I gived different value to sbuf[0,2], sbuf[1,2], sbuf[2,2] and sbuf[0,3], sbuf[1,3], sbuf[2,3].

But find that after `cuda.syncthreads()`, the values bacame same between sbuf[0,2] and sbuf[0,3], sbuf[1,2] and sbuf[1,3], sbuf[2,2] and sbuf[2,3].

It directly lead to the values of Xi_s, Xi1_s and Yi_s wrong.

These are my guesses according to what was printed inside the kernel.

@talonmies said relying on print statements inside kernels like this is dangerous.

So I want to know if it has an useful way to debug my code instead of printing statements inside kernels.

```
    ...

@cuda.jit
def calcu_T(D, T):
  ...

                    if bx==1 and tx==1:
                        print('5,c_x,c_y,L,c_index,bx,tx,ty,sbuf[0,ty],sbuf[1,ty],sbuf[2,ty],',c_x,',',c_y,',',L,',',c_index,',',bx,',',tx,',',ty,',',sbuf[0,ty],',',sbuf[1,ty],',',sbuf[2,ty])

                    cuda.syncthreads()

                    if bx==1 and tx==1:
                        print('1,c_x,c_y,L,c_index,bx,tx,ty,sbuf[0,ty],sbuf[1,ty],sbuf[2,ty],',c_x,',',c_y,',',L,',',c_index,',',bx,',',tx,',',ty,',',sbuf[0,ty],',',sbuf[1,ty],',',sbuf[2,ty])

                     ...
```

Comment: I have already told you once that relying on print statements inside kernels like this is dangerous. [SO] isn't a free debugging service. Please don't treat it like one

Comment: Is there a good way for numba to debug? Should I transfer the value to CPU for printing to see if It's right?

Comment: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/simulator.html#

Comment: Thank you. [pdb](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.31.0/cuda/simulator.html) is difficult to use. The interaction with it is difficult. Maybe I'm just new to it. I'll study more.

Answer (score 1):

As @talonmies said, printing statements inside kernels is not a good choice for debugging. If someone has the same problem, [this documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.31.0/cuda/simulator.html) is helpful, and more you should learn is [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), especially the debugger commands,such as 'p', 'c'.